# Is it safe to create a master branch in this way

Tags: git

When I created a git repository for my project, Git by default create the `master` branch for me, I pushed my code also there.

Then, from some point one year ago, I started working on a new branch "`develop`".

Now, I have a lot of things on `develop` branch, I would like to directly have a copy of develop on 'master' branch, is it safe (i.e. no work getlost), if I just delete the current **local & remote** `master` branch and branch off from `develop` to create a new `master` branch in order to have the same code in `develop` and `master` of my repo (both local and remote)?

Comment: What's wrong with making a pull request to master?

Comment: You mean rename `develop` to `master` and force push? If you are the only user then this is trivially safe; if you're not, it should similarly trivially be a complete no-no.

Comment: @JosephSerido , because there will be a lot of conflicts to fix, in stead of spending time resolve conflicts, it is easier if I just create a new master branch from develop branch.

Comment: @tripleee No, I don't mean that. I mean I delete the default master branch and create a new master branch from develop branch.

Comment: That's what renaming `develop` to `master` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that's unclear to me in your description:  Are there changes added to master after the commit from which you created develop?

If not, then you have something like this:

```
A <--(master)
 \
  B -- C -- D <--(develop)
```

In that case, if you want to update `master` content to look just like `develop`, merge `develop` into `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

By default this will do a "fast-forward", and you'll end with

```
A -- B -- C -- D <--(master)(develop)
```

If you want to preserve the branch topology - i.e. if you want to later be able to tell that the commits `B`, `C`, and `D` were done on a branch - then don't allow the fast-forward

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff master
```

And then you'll get

```
A ----------- M <--(master)
 \           /
  B -- C -- D <--(develop)
```

where `M` is a "merge commit"; but because `A` was an ancestor of `D` anyway, the content ("`TREE` object") at `M` will be the same ad `D`, as you can verify with `git diff master develop`.

On the other hand, if `master` has received changes (from you or anyone else), then your requirements ("make `master` match `develop`" and "don't lose changes") are somewhat in conflict.  In this case you start with

```
A -- X <--(master)
 \
  B -- C -- D <--(develop)
```

There are various ways to still move the `master` branch to `D` - but then you would lose `X` (unless you took extra steps to retain it, such as creating a new branch or tag at `master` before moving `master`).

Also note that any of these methods will result in having to "force push" the changes, which will cause problems for anyone else who's cloned the repo - so you'd have to coordinate with them (see `recovering from upstream rebase` in the `git rebase` docs - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase; whether or not you actually use the rebase command, this situation will apply).

The simplest way to move `master` would be

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
git push -f
```

If you don't want to lose `X` (or create a new branch for it), or you don't want to force push because of the impact on other developers, then consider these other options:

The normal procedure when branches have diverged would be to merge `develop` into `master`.  (Some people, liking linear histories, would first rebase `develop` onto `master` and then fast-forward `master` as in the previous example.)  The result will *not* generally be that `master` matches `develop`, because `master` will also have the changes from `X`.

You can perform a merge while still making `master` take on the content from `develop` (roughly, making the master commit record, relative to `master`, the "undo-ing" of `X` and the "do-ing" of `B`, `C`, and `D`).  In that case, the changes at `X` are still in the history (so they aren't entirely lost).  There are two ways to do that.  The better way is to revert the commits that are only on `master` (in our example, `X`).

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD
git merge develop
```

If there are multiple commits on `master`, you can revert them all in a single commit

```
git revert -n HEAD^ HEAD
git commit
```

After reverting but before the merge you could rebase `develop` onto `master` to keep the history linear if you want.

For the sake of completeness, I'll mention that you *could* include the revert of `X` in the merge commit itself; but unless merging `develop` to `master` would otherwise fail with conflicts, this creates an "evil merge" and may cause problems down the line; so it's probably not worth it.  (Especially because git doesn't make it quite as easy as you'd hope; it's easy to merge and discard the changes from the "other" branch you're merging in, but less easy to merge and discard the changes from the current branch.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to make `master` a copy of `develop` in the remote. You may lost all work that is on `master` an not on `develop`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
git push origin master
```

I don't know what is your history on both branch. If there are commits on `master` that are not on `develop`, this won't be the good solution because it will suggest a force push, which is not recommended.

Comment: This makes much more sense than deleting and renaming `master`, etc.

Comment: Unless there are no changes on master, this requires a force push (i.e. given instructions won't work); and if recommending a force push, you should at least reference reasonable documentation of the hazards that poses (i.e. "recovering from upstream rebase" documentation)  And if there *are* no changes on master, then it's better to just merge and let the branch fast-forward.

Comment: I agree that it is not recommended to force push, this is the sense of my last sentences (I will make it clearer). In this case I guess this is what it is needed.